# Responsive slider issues and bootstrap

Tags: css, slider, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to get the slides to center correctly. I am not sure what is going on

here is a link

www.xxx.com/matt

I have went into the JS files and did not find anything that could help. The images are the only thing i swap out in the default files.

Here is the link to the slider I am trying to use.

http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider/

The strange part is that it looks perfect on my iphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems your slider images are to small. 100% width of your slider is longer than your images.

Fix with setting the width of your images to a higher value:

```
.responsive-slider .slides ul li .slide-body img
{
max-width: 100%;
width:1200px; //for example
}
```

**update**

> I want the slider to be same size as image 900 x 300.

```
.responsive-slider
{
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 900px;
      position: relative;
}
```